# KO 3.2 - libraries vs helpers

Tags: php, kohana

Well, this will be some pretty short question - what is the difference between `APPATH/classes/libraries` and `APPATH/classes/helpers` folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. Those are something you'd make. Everything is just a "class".